# Xcode Organizer Documentation missing

Tags: xcode, xcode-organizer

I can't find a way to enable the Documentation Organizer. I have already gone to Preferences>Downloads>and installed the "iOS 7" & "XCode 5 doc set".

I am running the latest XCode 5.0.2

I'm attaching a screenshot of what I see.[image]

Comment: its in Help Tab, use shortcut alt + cmd + ?

Comment: Ok, that should work. I'm used to seeing an icon next to archives in Organizer. I thought there was a way to enable it on that window.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's under **xcode -> Help -> Documentation and API Reference** now. Shortcut is "shift + cmd+ ?" or "alt + cmd + ?".